# Pandas read_csv to adding some very small values to the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When i use pandas read_csv, pandas add some little value to the dataframe, it went from -0.079257 to -0.07925700000000001, why is this happening and how can I fix this? It also only happen to some specific values, while others seems fine.

I've tried using float_precision but seems doesn't do anything, I'm new to pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('filepath') 
print(df.iat[0,0])
```

[Dataset Link](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00459/avila.zip)

I changed the dataset file type from txt to csv manually using notepad.

[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVUGG.png)

Comment: Could you add part of the data of the csv file and your expected output, so others can help you figure out the problem.

Comment: already put the link to the dataset, i expected to get the same value from the dataset for example like -0.079257, instead i get -0.07925700000000001

Answer (score 2):

This is because your original data have a np.float32 precision.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./avila/avila-ts.txt')
print(df.iat[0,0])    # 0.13029200000000002

# stored as np.float32
df.to_csv('./my.csv',float_format=np.float32, index_label=False)
df_1 = pd.read_csv('./my.csv')
print(df_1.iat[0,0])   # 0.13029200000000002

# stored as np.float16
df.to_csv('./my.csv',float_format=np.float16, index_label=False)
df_1 = pd.read_csv('./my.csv')
print(df_1.iat[0,0])   # 0.1302
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it does the job, but I still don't know why it happen in the first place.

Comment: This is because these data themselves have more precision depending on the float precision you chose when you stored the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your data is structured. could you open the data and check, better still screenshot.

```
data = pandas.read_csv('filepath')
data.head()
```

Comment: I've put some screenshot up, I'm still new to this thing